# How can the Quantum Hall Effect consist of Topological Phase Transitions when there is no changing Topological Invariant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-transition, topology, quantum-hall-effect

I have read this [article](https://www.nature.com/news/the-strange-topology-that-is-reshaping-physics-1.22316) about Topology in Physics and had some problems understanding the Topological Phase Transition of the Quantum Hall Effect.

The way I understood Topological Phase Transition, it is a change in the topological invariant. The article mentions the following things:

1. Every Vortex has a winding number.
2. Winding Numbers are Topological Invariants.
3. The total sum of Winding Numbers in a system can not change (Chen-Number).
4. A new Vortex always appears with an Anti-Vortex.

Now the explanation for the Quantum Hall effect shall be, that the underlying shape of the inspected matter was (abstract) like a doughnut. When the magnetic field ramps up, Vortices are appearing. So there is to be a Topological Phase transition every time the electrical resistance jumps (right?). This Topological Phase Transition occurs because of the new Vortices.

But whenever a new pair of Vortices appears and separates, the total sum of Winding Numbers does not change. So how can there be a Topological Phase Transition, when there is no changing Topological Invariant? Did I understand Phase Transition in a wrong way?

Comment: This is a very good question. The physics of the jumps between the quantum Hall Plateaus is a very interesting, profound and rather complicated subject. Please look up *Hall plateau transition*, you should be able to find many references containing explanations and models of this transition.